# Inconsistent recognition accuracy in Sphinx 4 (beta version 6) hello-world demo

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

Please why doesn't the Sphinx4 (beta version 6) 'Hello World' demo work consistently well
all the time?

I have look at the Programmers' Guide and other sources and it seems the problem is not from
my end.

Answer (score 0):

Speech recognition is always imprecise, you can't expect some code to work 100% of the time. It might work in 90% and fail in 10%. That 90% should be sufficient to build the application.

The question is not why it fails, the question is how often does it fail. You need to collect some statistics on that. If it fails 1 time of 20 it's expected. If it fails 10 times of 20 attempts, it's most likely in issue.

If you think it's still an issue you need to do the following:

1. Record audio you are trying to recognize
2. Share it on CMUSphinx forum so developers can take a look on it.

You can learn about concepts of speech recognition in CMUSphinx tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/tutorial